# Enviar correo usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página que necesita enviar correos de parte del cliente utilizando javascript. Hasta hace poco me funcionaba la siguiente instrucción:

```
<a href="mailto:***@gmail.com?subject=Asunto del mensaje&body=Hola Es un nuevo correo">Enviar<a/>
```

Pero ahora no responde y tampoco da error.

Lo he intentado utilizando

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL
```

y

```
window.URL.createObjectURL
```

Pero sólo abre el Outlook con los datos enviados pero no lo envía (debo pulsar la opción de enviar).

Comment: mira esto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Answer (score 2):

lo que deseas hacer no puede realizarse con javascript. necesitas un lenguaje como php o C# en MVC para poder realizar el proceso de envió de correo sin necesidad de utilizar el outlook del equipo.

Si quieres utilizar el outlook te funcionaria perfectamente como lo estas usando. pero si deseas enviar un correo desde la web tienes que desarrollar un modulo de correo o utilizar un API de envió de correo que reciba parámetros y realice el trabajo. puedes buscar en google, se encuentran varias.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un envío de correo necesitas un cliente de correo puesto que los navegadores no implementan el protocolo SMTP, es imposible hacerlo en el navegador.

Javascript es solamente un lenguaje de programación y esta sujeto a las restricciones de la plataforma donde se ejecute el interprete en este caso la plataforma es el navegador.

Por lo tanto la única alternativa que tienes para enviar correos desde el browser es llamar al cliente como Outlook en Windows o Mail en macOS dependiendo del cliente de correo instalado en el sistema operativo... si aun así quieres gestionar el envío de correo tu mismo y no pasar por estos clientes lo que puedes hacer es implementar el servidor de correos en tu servidor que envíe desde el servidor por SMTP los correos y si quieres que sea con Javascript entonces usas Node.js, pero esta es una solución muy complicada para el caso que presentas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu etiqueta "a" que cierra esta mal escrita por eso no te funciona! proba cerrarla de esta manera
`<a href="mailto:***@gmail.com?subject=Asunto del mensaje&body=Hola Es un nuevo correo">Enviar</a>`